# Where are constant NSStrings allocated?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsstring, constants, foundation

I understand that constant CStrings are allocated statically, rather than on the heap.

I also noticed that constant NSStrings have an infinite retain count. Does it hold true that constant NSStrings are also allocated statically, rather than on the heap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constant NSStrings are of class `NSConstantString`, and thus act like atoms in lisp; they hang around. -> **`NSConstantStrings` are allocated statically.** That is, if you use `@"cow"` in two separate places in your code, they will be referencing the very same object.

The reason why `NSConstantStrings` even have a retain count is because they inherit from `NSObject`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That makes a lot of sense.